# Setting the height of the child div with percents

Tags: html, css

I have a child div inside of parent div, something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">

 </div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to set height of the child, using percents, so it can be bigger than its content.Setting `#child { height: 150% }` won't accomplished nothing.Parent div doesn't have any height set, and I don't want to use pixels.So, the real question is, **how to set child div bigger** than its contents by using percents ?

EDIT: Maybe I was not clear.What I need is visual equivalent of this

```
#child{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
        <p>TESTING</p>
    </div>
```

using percents.

Answer (score 1):

in css, add overflow parameter

```
#child{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This shoud be fine....

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow:auto;">
 <div id="child">

 </div>
</div>
```